# div crossfade on arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm familiar with HTML/CSS but am new to the world of Javascript and jQuery, so I've been stumped on this problem.

I'm trying to fade out the current div which contains an image, and fade in the div that is directly next, here is an [example](http://emerylena.com/projects/nike)
. This will be eventually applied to a Tumblr photo blog so I can't target the images individually.
I've tried several different methods and the jQuery code below is the one that I've come closest with however it still skips divs and gets stuck. 
All help is greatly appreciated :)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="post"><img src="1.jpg" alt="1"></div>
    <div class="post"><img src="2.jpg" alt="2"></div>
    <div class="post"><img src="3.jpg" alt="3"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.post{
    position: absolute;
    width: 480px;
    height: auto;
    top: 120px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -240px;
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            switch(e.which) {

                case 37: // left
                        $('.post').fadeOut().prev().fadeIn();
                break;

                case 39: // right
                        $('.post').fadeOut().next().fadeIn();                                   
                break;

             default: return; 
            }
             e.preventDefault(); 
        });

});
```

Comment: Did you get my edited demo to work?

Comment: looking at the code through chrome dev tools it seems to be making multiples of the .post's

Comment: what do you mean by multiples of .post? Don't you have 3 .post divs? you can control that through the js code. it puts all your post div into an array and make a slide show. let me know if there's a problem.

Comment: the number of .posts isn't actually 3, it's a variable that changes as the blog is updated via Tumblr. I added a variable in js to account for that but google chrome dev tools shows that each time it rotates through, it doesn't delete the previous divs, therefore making multiples.

Comment: Don't know how you write your js but here's my update http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/h3A8M/2/
It will work out how many .posts you have and update that dynamically if this is what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/h3A8M/)

You could use `indexNum-- and indexNum++` to navigate through images.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Godinall, but this code swaps the src of the current image to a predetermined src. I'm looking to make a crossfade that will fade to the following div without individually targeting it because the image will be sourced from the blog. Here is the html I should have included to clarify:
     `<div class="content">
        {block:Posts}

 {block:Photo}

 <div class="post"> 

  <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />

 {/block:Photo}

 </div>
 
 {/block:Posts}
</div>`

Comment: All right then, I have updated my demo as per your request. Just add a div for the divs to slide in. <div class="postslide"></div> See demo here http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/h3A8M/1/